# How to find the name of the folder given to selenium webdriver object?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, directory

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

So this gives me a browser object and a new window, what I want to know is how to tell the name of the folder, in my temp directory, where this object's information is being kept.  It does a good job of deleting the folder most of the time on browser.quit() but sometimes it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's at:

```
 browser.profile.path
```

You can have a look at the [Python code for Firefox profiles](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py).